# Nhibernate lazy loading a set not working

Tags: nhibernate, collections, lazy-loading

I'm using nhibernate2.1 as part of spring.net 1.3.  I have the following declaration as part of my mapping.  My understanding is that this object should not load unless the getter is called.  I have a break point set on the setter and also dump all nhibernate SQL statements to the logger.  In part of my testing, I've actually created a brand new child object and a brand new property on my original object (hence the "2" on the names) so I'm positive that property is not being accessed anywhere.  Despite this, as soon as my parent object loads, I can verify that this property is loaded.  So...what am I missing here?

```
<set name="UserCustomer2" lazy="true">
    <key column="[FK_USERS]" />
    <one-to-many class="UserCustomer2" />
</set>
```

@A: here is my property:

```
private ICollection<UserCustomer2> _UserCustomer2 = new HashSet<UserCustomer2>();
public virtual ICollection<UserCustomer2> UserCustomer2
{
    get { return _UserCustomer2; }
    set { this._UserCustomer2 = value; }
}
```

and here is how I request the parent object:

```
IQuery query = dao.GetQuery("FROM UserImpl u WHERE u.UserName = :username AND u.Password = :password");
query.SetParameter("username", username);
query.SetParameter("password", password);
IList users = query.List();
```

Comment: How are you verifying the object is loaded? Are you sure you're not loading it with test code or debugger etc.?

Comment: I see the SQL statement executed in the logs and I put a breakpoint on the setter.  When I execute, the breakpoint is hit and when I hover over the "value" in the setter, it is the fully populated object with correct data from the database.

Comment: Could you show how you're querying the DB for your Parent object and how UserCustomer2 property looks like in Parent class?

Comment: Sure thing; I've updated my original post

Comment: If you omit the breakpoint do you still see the second query in the logs? Maybe the debugger is pre-loading it...

Comment: Are you correctly referencing bytecode provider assembly? Like NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dotjoe, you led me down the right path. I tested out quite a few scenarios and based on breakpoints and the logged SQL statements I've determined that setting breakpoints does NOT trigger the lazy load.  However, when you hover over the property to inspect it while in debug mode, it DOES in fact hydrate the object. I guess that sort of makes sense but I was assuming when I inspected the object, I would just see a proxy object instead of the fully hydrated object.  I'm surprised that a debug mode action would trigger the lazy load -- I assumed that would only be triggered from actual application code.  The other thing I'm curious about is if the setter is ALWAYS called and just passed a proxy object or if it was only called BECAUSE I had put a breakpoint in the setter.  I would assume the former but so far my assumptions have been wrong.  If anyone can provide some insights, I'm very curious how this actually works behind the scenes.

Comment: another thing to check might be to remove the private backing field or tell NH about it via `access="field.camelacse-underscore"`. The way you have it might be screwing with the proxy object? just a guess...